# My cpanel doesn’t have the “setup python app”

Tags: python, django, deployment, cpanel

I want to deploy my Django application using cpanel, but my problem is that my cpanel does not have the setup python application option in its software section, please help me, this is my first project, I don't want to fail in this project.[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Setup python app" is provisioned by your CPanel provider. which basically means you will see that option only when they are part of your cPanel package and are enabled by the vendor-cPanel admin.

But even if that option is not available, end of the day Django is just one of the web applications which can be installed manually on the instance upon which your cPanel files are hosted.

For this you will need access to your webserver via some protocol, let's say SSH.

More details can be found out on this article:
https://www.milesweb.in/hosting-faqs/install-and-configure-django-from-cpanel/

Hope this helps, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am going to try with ssh :)

Comment: Great. Nasir, it is a little lengthy exercise to set it up manually but you will get to learn a lot. Good luck man & don't forget to accept the answer If it helped. Thanks.